# How can I access content of a XamGrid Column

Tags: silverlight, xamgrid

I have created a XamGrid in a silverlight page in WCF. in which I have a column called "status" . It has three values which are : complete, start, ongoing. for these values I want to set add an image beside the text.
How can I access XamGrid column contents from Code behind. I have used something like:

```
XamGrid1.column.[2].key
```

but it is returning me the column name. and I want the value in that column.. Please someone help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi add a event Cellclicked to your datagrid

```
              if (this.Yourdatagrid.ActiveCell != null)
             {
                Custom.DuoInventory.Dealer OBJ= new YourObject();
                if (((List<Yourdatasource>)Yourdatagrid.ItemsSource).Count == 0) return;
                OBJ = (YourObject)Yourdatagrid.ActiveCell.Row.Data;
              }
```

then you can access your each member.